# Windows Phone 8 Map : {System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.}

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, maps

I have a Map control in my XAML as:

```
<maps:Map x:Name="MapViewControl" Height="480">

        </maps:Map>
```

I am populating the MapLayer in code behind as:

```
 MapLayer layer = new MapLayer();
        MapOverlay overLay;
        layer.Clear();
        foreach (var item in listOfItems)
        {
            overLay = new MapOverlay();
            overLay.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(item.Latitude, item.Longitude);
            overLay.Content = redCircle;
            overLay.PositionOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);

            layer.Add(overLay);

        }
        MapViewControl.Layers.Add(layer);
```

EDIT: The above code is the Load event on the Page.

I am getting a "Value does not fall within the expected range" error.

Any idea?

Comment: on which line are you getting this exception?

Comment: @Aman Once all the code gets executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was the redCircle (:)). This was a reference to a Ellipse shape I created. Somehow the Mapping framework doesn't like to refer to the same instance of the Content to all the overlays.

Before:

```
 overLay.Content = redCircle;
```

After (that is, now):

```
overLay.Content = CreateShape();
```

Where CreateShape is defined as:

```
 private Ellipse CreateShape()
    {
        Ellipse redCircle = new Ellipse();
         redCircle.Width = 10;
         redCircle.Height = 10;
         redCircle.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
         return redCircle;
    }
```

So, it gets created each time in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The Constructor of new `GeoCoordinate()` is expecting a value of the parameter from -90.0 to 90.0 If you don't meet this criteria, a `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` get thrown.

can you verify the values of `item.Latitute` and `item.Longitude`?

if not, please debug and step over every line to see, where the error occurs. Or provide some sample values of your instance of `listOfItems`

Comment: If there is one item in listOfItems, it works fine. If there are more than one, it blows.